# How to use System.Windows.Forms in Windows Phone 8.1?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, dom

I want create a very simple HTML parser application. I read lots of tutorial and lots of developer use this class: HtmlDocument.
I want use this class in my app too but I am not able to add reference to System.Windows.Forms.

I try to add reference in Project > Reference but I can't find Windows.Forms.
How can I fix this problem and use HtmlDocument?

I use Visual Studio 2013.

Thank you.

This is my very simple code:

```
namespace ParseHTML
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

            this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;
            string url = "http://www.alvolante.it/";
            download(url);
        }

        private async void download(string url)
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            string risposta = await client.GetStringAsync(new Uri(url)); //download html della pagina web
            HtmlDocument hc = new HtmlDocument();  //error here, missing reference or assembly?


        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. WinForms is not supported nor even implemented on Windows Phone (Windows Mobile 6.5.3 released in early 2010 is the last "Windows" phone OS to support WinForms by way of the Compact Framework).

To process HTML in applications, I suggest HtmlAgilityPack instead, which provides a fault-tolerant DOM manipulation library: http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com

Comment: Thank you for reply. So wich class I have to use for parse an HTML webpage?

Comment: Here is sample code doing it: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/HTML-Parser-Code-MSDN-fe21fd6d

Comment: I read that HTML Agility Pack is not supported by WP 8.1, is this wrong information?

Comment: @Gianluca the downloadable binaries won't work as-is on WP, but if you download the sources and rebuild specifically for WP it should then work.

Comment: I add HTMLAgilitypack via Nuget. Now I test it and probably I will accept your answer. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I try HTMLAgilityPack but there are lots of problems, first of all I read that I can't use XML.XPath in WP 8.1, so I can't use some methods of Agility Pack